# ¿Como validar input para que solo admita letras y tildes en dispositivos móviles?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un query que funciona perfecto en web, pero en dispositivos móviles, no admite la validación, existe la posibilidad de hacer la validación para móviles?

Este es mi query en JS:

```
  function check(e) {
    key=e.keyCode || e.which;

    teclado=String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();

    letras="áéíóúqwertyuiopasdfghjklñzxcvbnm ";

    especiales="8-37-38-46-164-46";

    teclado_especial=false;

    for(var i in especiales){
        if(key==especiales[i]){
            teclado_especial=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(letras.indexOf(teclado)==-1 && !teclado_especial){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Y que evento llama a esa función??

Comment: onkeypress="return check(event)"

Comment: Prueba cambiando a onkeyup. De todas formas el código que tienes está malo, quizás deberías buscar una alternativa usando expresiones regulares